# UIImage Base64 encoding fails

Tags: iphone, uiimage, base64, nsdata

i'm trying to convert a UIImage which comes from the iPhones photo library to a base64 encoded string. My problem is that the output of the base64 encoded string does not match a base64 string which i've created on a online base64 encoder for jpegs.

Here is my code:

```
NSData *myAttachment = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(myImage, 1.0);
NSString *base64encodedAttachment = [attachment base64EncodingWithLineLenght:76];
```

While "attachment" is a string which will be part of an url request.
Why does the base64 code not match the "normal" from encoding websites encoding? Is there something special about UIImage oder NSData?

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

It may happen that the `UIImage` is re-encoded when you call `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` and therefore it is not identical to the JPEG image you have uploaded to that online site. If you want to be 100% sure that the base64 encoder works as expected, save the JPEG representation that comes out of `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` to a JPEG file and upload that file to the online tool to obtain the base64 representation to compare your output with.

Comment: You are right, i've tested your suggestion. But how can I convert the NSdata back to the original data provided by the jpeg, because otherwise my webserver won't recognize the image encoding.

Comment: one addition. the new file which i've created out of the NSData object is of lower quality than the original one. Is there a possibilty to set the quality to its original value?

Comment: The only way not to lose quality compared to the original image is not to re-encode it. Either you save it as a PNG file (because PNG uses a lossless compression algorithm), in which case the PNG file should be identical pixel-by-pixel to the decompressed JPEG image, or you get the path of the original image file on the file system and load that directly into an ``NSData``, skipping the ``UIImage``.

Comment: maybe i'm missing something in my requestheader. my header contains so far: Content-Type "application/x-www-urlencoded", content-disposition "multipart/form-data" and a few other header information which have nothing to do with the data im trying to send.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to use this `jpeg` file in the messageBody of the mailComposer.. then i must clear you buddy...

You cannot use the local images inside the mailbody of mailComposer, the image shud be available on the server and used in the mailbody by passing `url` of the same..

If you're trying something else...i would say follow "Tamas" :)

Comment: ok here is what i'm trying to do. I'd like to create an url body stream which contains for expample ...attachment=<base64encodedattachment>&number=123456789... and so on. what am I missing?

Comment: it won't work buddy.. even i've spent 2 days searching for the stuff like dat... :/

u have to use the html body and pass the image link inside the body..